# Multiple axios get requests in socket.io. Sending two events via `socket.emit` at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io, axios

I am trying to create multiple axios requests in socket.io. If I have simultaneously:

`socket.emit ("Emit1", req1.data);`
`socket.emit ("Emit2", req2.data);`

`socket.emit("Emit2", req2.data);` works. `socket.emit ("Emit1", req1.data);` does not work.

When I remove `socket.emit("Emit2", req2.data);` --> `emit1`  works.

How to combine it so that it works simultaneously?.

Can I create two servers. One supporting the first component and request get `url1` and a second server that supports request`url2`?

```
const Emit = async socket => {
    try{
      const [req1, req2] = await Promise.all([
        axios.get(url1, {
          headers: {

          }
        }),
        axios.get(url2, {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
          }
        })
      ]);

      socket.emit("Emit1", req1.data);
      socket.emit("Emit2", req2.data); 
    }

    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
};
```

**Client**

First component:

```
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get
        axios({
            url,
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                scores: res.data,
                activeTab: res.data[0].id
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })      
}


componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const endpoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'; 

    if (prevState.scores !== this.state.scores) {
        const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);
        socket.on("Emit1", data => this.setState({ 
            scores: data 
        }));
    }
}
```

Second component:

```
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get
        axios({
            url,
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                abcd: res.data
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })      
}


componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const endpoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'; 

    if (prevState.abcd !== this.state.abcd) {
        const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);
        socket.on("Emit2", data => this.setState({ 
            abcd: data 
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your handler function? How are you handling both events? Can you post that in the question?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty How does it operate on the client's side? That's what you mean?

Comment: Yes. the client side code.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty  I updated my question

Comment: I think you are sending to incorrect socket. Can you do `io.emit` instead of `socket.emit` where `io` is your socket-io instance.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty Can we talk on chat?

Comment: What has axios got to do with this? Are you using `http` requests or `tcp` web sockets for communication? Is it a problem with the `axios` requests or the socket `emit` ?

Comment: @Cristy Now is the problem because the application hangs, I updated my question.

Comment: @ArtiraChakraborty   When I set  `io.emit` instead of `socket.emit` app is hang. When one of the two `socket.emit (" Emit1 ", req1.data)` is set;
or `socket.emit (" Emit2 ", req2.data); ` it's work good. But they do not work at the same time.

Comment: @Cristy  When I set `io.emit` instead of `socket.emit` app is hang. When one of the two `socket.emit (" Emit1 ", req1.data)` is set; or `socket.emit (" Emit2 ", req2.data);`  it's work good. But they do not work at the same time.

Comment: Show how you're calling your Emit function, are you passing the socket instance or the io instance?

Comment: @MiltonFilho     on the client side?

Comment: @MiltonFilho   I  updated my question

Comment: Can you provide a minimal git repo to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working on your question for a while now and this are my conclusions:

#### Event emission works just fine

I've reconstructed your backend this way:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const http = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(http)
const port = 3003

app.use(express.json())

app.get('/emit', async({ res }) => {
    const [data1, data2] = await Promise.all([fakeApiCall(1), fakeApiCall(2)])
    io.emit('Emit1',data1)
    io.emit('Emit2',data2)
    res.status(200).json('emitted')
})

const fakeApiCall = id =>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        setTimeout(() => resolve(`data${id}`), 3000)
    })
}

http.listen(port, () => console.log('listening on port ' + port))
```

Essencially that's exactly what you are doing, and works just fine, both events are emmited after `Promise.all` solves all promises.

#### Frontend setup works

After that I've made a version of your frontend:

App.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import ComponentA from './ComponentA'
import ComponentB from './ComponentB'

const App = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <ComponentA />
            <ComponentB />
        </>
    )
}


export default App
```

Component A :

```
import React from 'react'
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client'

class ComponentA extends React.Component {
    state = {
        data: null
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        setTimeout(() => this.setState({data: 'bla'}), 2000)
    }


    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        const endpoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:3003';

        if (prevState.data !== this.state.data) {
            const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);
            socket.on("Emit1", data => this.setState({ data }))
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                {data}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ComponentA
```

Component B :

```
import React from 'react'
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client'

class ComponentB extends React.Component {
    state = {
        data: null
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        setTimeout(() => this.setState({data: 'bla'}), 2000)
    }


    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        const endpoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:3003';

        if (prevState.data !== this.state.data) {
            const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);
            socket.on("Emit2", data => this.setState({ data }))
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                {data}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ComponentB
```

And surprisingly... It works just fine! So, what is the difference here? Everything looks the same (how the events are emitted, how the listener is only inserted in `componentDidUpdate`, how the state changes after an async call in `componentDidMount`).
So the only thing that can possibly be interfering is the axios call you make inside `componentDidMount`, cause in both components the `io.listen` isn't setted at `componentDidMount` how it should be (I assume you have reasons for that), so both components MUST update the state before the event is emmited, otherwise if the properties `data` or `abcd` don't get updated in time the event listener will be called after the backend emits the data. And your claim about how if you omit `Emit2` `Emit1` will work just fine. But, what about omit `Emit1`? `Emit2` will work as well? Looks like a race condition, something in `componentA`'s `componentDidMount` is preventing `componentB` from updating or vice-versa

### Possible Solution

Place the io's listeners in `componentDidMount` in both components to determine if this is the case. Cause honestly, I couldn't think in any other problem that may be causing this.

Comment: I've already tried to put in componentDidMount (). But in the component 'A' in `setState ({})` I have set 'activeTab: res.data [0] .id` active tab before loading the component. When I click on 'tab 3', it automatically moves to `tab 1` ->` activeTab: res.data [0] .id`

Comment: I didn't solve it. I delete activeTab:res.data[0].id. from this.setState. Now I have a problem how set activeTab in component didmount

Comment: hi, do you mind having a look at my question for some reason my frontend stops connecting with the backend after exactly 4 messages https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74191884/expo-app-connection-with-nodejs-stops-working-with-sockets